# Android application used to run in Eclipse but now, it doesn't

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text-to-speech

My application was running perfectly fine. I closed Eclipse for few days and now that I want to run it, the emulator starts but the application doesn't run. It prompt this error saying:
 `The application Pico TTS (process com.svox..pico) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.`

Apparently it is because of my `TextToSpeech`, but what about it? There's no error shown in the application.

In my Log Cat I receive such messages:

```
at dalvik.system.nativestart.main(native method)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:433)
at com.kelamrsan.MPActivity.onCreate(MPActivity.java:47)
```

Cheers.

Comment: What does it say in your LogCat?

Comment: Does you application actually use that functionality?  The Android emulator (and to a lesser degree Android in general) is notorious for error and advisory messages from pre-packaged applications and components which have nothing to do with your development project.  On a less than blindingly fast host system, emulator built-in apps may force close at startup seemingly for that reason alone.

Comment: I appreciate your concerns.
@ Justin: I updated my question and added the messages on Log Cat.
@ Chris: Well thank you for the explanation. Yes, my application is using the TextToSpeech.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with Eclipse, you are getting runtime error from emulator.  Make sure that emulator you are using has TTS engine, if that's the things you are using.

Comment: @minhaz: How come the problem was not here before?

Comment: @Shawn I am even not sure, where exactly you are having problem. Logcat message refer to issue with android built in TTS engine. Are you using that engine? if anything happened due to eclipse your application won't compile. Eclipse issues are usually compile time not run time.